# Do you know what fractal this is?

Tags: fractals

I want to write a program and draw this fractal but I don't know the recursion step. Does anyone know any information about this fractal?

[image]

Comment: It's a variation on the Sierpinski triangle.

Comment: see [Sierpiński arrowhead curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_curve#Arrowhead_curve).

Answer (score 2):

This fractal looks strikingly similar to **Sierpinski triangle**.

[image]

Sierpinski triangle is made in the following way:

1. Start with an equilateral triangle.
2. Subdivide it into four smaller congruent equilateral triangles and remove the central triangle.
3. Repeat step 2 with each of the remaining smaller triangles infinitely.

The big problem with finding recursive steps for your fractal is not only that it is slightly different from Sierpinski triangle but that it is also constructed backwards.

So I looked for different variations of Sierpinski triangle and what I found is something called **Sierpinski arrowhead curve**.

The steps to making it are the following:

1. Draw an imaginary line. Think of it as a base of an equilateral triangle.
2. Move up (while drawing) one side. Stop halfway.
3. Move parallel to base till you reach the other side.
4. Move down the side to the base line.
5. Apply same procedure to all lines. The triangles on slanting lines must point inwards. The triangle on the horizontal line must point outwards.

[image]

My source and also a great resource for programming with fractals: https://www.slideshare.net/GurpalSingh29/awesome-introduction-to-recursion-in-programming-with-fractals-56101307